# "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping value" for iPhone LED

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I am trying to activate the iPhone LED with this code (connected to a UIButton):

```
@IBAction func toggleFlash(sender: AnyObject) {

    let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    if (device.hasTorch) {
        device.lockForConfiguration(nil)
        if (device.torchMode == AVCaptureTorchMode.On) {
            device.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchMode.Off
        } else {
            device.setTorchModeOnWithLevel(1.0, error: nil)
        }
        device.unlockForConfiguration()
}
}
```

Then I get the error:
**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

For the following code:

```
if (device.hasTorch) {
```

It also says: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=...)
What should I do, add delete?!!

THANK YOU!

Comment: you have to verify that device is not nil before call "if (device.hasTorch)"

Comment: @HoaParis How would I go about doing that?

Comment: I added an answer to your question. Whenever you get this kind of error 'unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping", it means your try to unwrap an variable that does not have value (or that is nil). In this case, the correction is just do the test if object != nil before do your work on that object.

Answer (score 2):

`defaultDeviceWithMediaType()` returns `nil` if there is no device available for that media type. You must check to make sure there is a device before calling other methods on it

```
@IBAction func toggleFlash(sender: AnyObject) {

    if let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {
        if (device.hasTorch) {
            device.lockForConfiguration(nil)
            if (device.torchMode == AVCaptureTorchMode.On) {
                device.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchMode.Off
            } else {
                device.setTorchModeOnWithLevel(1.0, error: nil)
            }
            device.unlockForConfiguration()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Swift 1.2, you can do the check with this code:

```
if let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) where device.hasTorch {
    //do your work with device
} else {
    NSLog("Device is nil or device does not have Torch")
}
```

In Swift 1.2, the pattern "if let" is more powerful. According to the release notes:

> The “if let” construct has been expanded to allow testing multiple
>   optionals and guarding conditions in a single if (or while) statement
>   using syntax similar to generic constraints:

```
if let a = foo(), b = bar() where a < b,
let c = baz() {
 }
```